# Use of Requirements.lock file in Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to understand the usage of Requirements.lock file . For using a dependent chart , we can make use of Requirements.yaml . Based on documentation

> **Requirements.lock** : rebuild the charts/ directory based on the requirements.lock file
>
> **Requirements.yaml** : update charts/ based on the contents of
>   requirements.yaml

Can someone explain the difference and usage of lock file and do we need to checking requirements.lock file in the repo too ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This article](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/create-your-first-helm-chart/) says it well:

> Much like a runtime language dependency file (such as Python’s requirements.txt), the requirements.yaml file allows you to manage your chart’s dependencies and their versions. When updating dependencies, a lockfile is generated so that subsequent fetching of dependencies use a known, working version.

The **requirements.yaml** file lists only the immediate dependencies that your chart needs. This makes it easier for you to focus on your chart.

The **requirements.lock** file lists the exact versions of immediate dependencies *and* their dependencies *and* their dependencies *and so forth*. This allows `helm` to precisely track the entire dependency tree and recreate it exactly as it last worked--even if some of the dependencies (or their dependencies) are updated later.

Here's roughly how it works:

1. You create the initial **requirements.yaml** file. You run `helm install` and **helm** creates the **requirements.lock** file as it builds the dependency tree.
2. On the next `helm install`, **helm** will ensure that it uses the same versions identified in the **requirements.lock** file.
3. At some later date, you update the **requirements.yaml** file. You run `helm install` (or `helm upgrade`) and **helm** will notice your changes and update the **requirements.lock** file to reflect them.

Comment: So basically without a Lock file, helm would be forced to download all the dependencies again because it wouldnt know which versions are deployed?