# Conditionally manage Helm chart dependencies without keeping the child charts inside 'charts' directory

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I currently have 3 Helm repositories with the following structure:

```
repoA/
├── templates/
├── Chart.yaml
├── values.yaml

repoB/
├── templates/
├── Chart.yaml
├── values.yaml

masterRepo/
├── templates/
├── Chart.yaml
├── values.yaml
├── requirements.yaml
```

The requirements.yaml file from ***masterRepo*** is something like below:

```
dependencies:
- name: repoA
  version: "1.0"
  repository: "file://../repoA"
  condition: repoA.enabled
- name: repoB
  version: "1.0"
  repository: "file://../repoB"
  condition: repoB.enabled
```

I would like to only use ***masterRepo*** to deploy the dependent Helm charts.

I know I can manually put all the child repositories in the `masterRepo/charts` and it will work but I wanna keep these repositories independent so that other master-repositories can use any of

What to do to make parent Helm chart detect all the required Helm charts and install them conditionally (based on `repoX.enabled` variable) without keeping the dependent repositories inside the `charts` directory of the Master-helm-chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have multiple Helm charts at different locations in the system, you can create dependencies without changing their location.

With the structure specified in the question, we can add dependencies in ***requirements.yaml*** (for Helm version: `2.x.x`) or ***Chart.yaml*** (for Helm version:`3.x.x`). I am currently using ***Helm v2.16.1***.

Now simply run `helm dependency update` or `helm dep up` from inside the `masterRepo` directory and a ***charts*** directory gets created. Now the updated structure of ***masterRepo*** looks like:

```
masterRepo/
├── charts/
       └── chartA-1.tgz
       └── chartB-1.tgz
├── templates/
├── Chart.yaml
├── requirements.lock
├── requirements.yaml
├── values.yaml
```

The new files/directories added are:

1. ***ChartA-1.tgz*** and ***ChartB-1.tgz*** [TAR Archive files](https://www.winzip.com/win/en/tgz-file.html) which are nothing but zipped ***chartA*** and ***chartB*** charts.
2. ***requirements.lock***: Used to rebuild the charts/ directory. Read more about this file in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702445/use-of-requirements-lock-file-in-helm-charts).

To install the child charts conditionally, you can the following the ***values.yaml*** file of the ***masterRepo***:

```
repoA:
  enabled: True
repoB:
  enabled: True
```

Now a simple `helm install` command from inside the ***masterRepo*** will deploy ***masterRepo*** as well as it's dependencies (***chartA*** and ***chartB***).

Hope this helps. Happy Helming!